# MySQL SELECT colums where both columns are unique

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unique

I have the following table.

```
id title  content
1  title1 content1
2  title1 content2
3  title1 content3
4  title2 content1
5  title2 content2
6  title2 content3
7  title3 content1
```

The result I want is only the first row, because for all other rows, either the title or the content is not unique. This is what I want:

```
id title  content
1  title1 content1
5  title2 content2
```

**Edit: Row 5 is also unique**

I want to show only the rows/columns when the title is unique (not already selected) and when the content is also unique (not already selected). How to do this?

Group by gives me the following result

```
`SELECT * FROM `posts` GROUP BY title`

id title  content
1  title1 content1
4  title2 content1
7  title3 content1
```

So this shows also row 4 and 7, but the content of them is not unique

```
 `SELECT * FROM `posts` GROUP BY title, content`
```

shows all rows.

How to get the result I want?

I was thinking of a sub query, but this is not an option as the context is a WP_query().

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: see my comments for more clarification

row 1 is not more unique. But it should display the first result and then after that it should only display unique results. Row 2 an 3 should not be displayed because the title is the same and already in the results (row 1) Row 4 should not be displayed because that content is already in row 1. Row 5 should be displayed as mentioned by pjd Row 6 and 7 should not be displaye because of the title or content are not unique.

Row 5 is indeed unique, good spot. Also Row 1 is more authoritative simply because it's the first result. The order however does not matter much.**

Comment: What makes `1 title1 content1` more unique than `2 title1 content2`? I don't understand your business rules.

Comment: I don't follow.  In what sense are the title and content of row 1 unique?  There are two other rows with the same title, and two other rows with the same content.

Comment: He wants to stop selecting content after `1 title1 content1` because that has already come back as a result, and every other record either has `title1` or `content1` in it.

Comment: Ah, you mean you want the *first*. After 'adding' the first occurrence of 'title1' to the result set, the second one would not be unique anymore. NB, why is  subquery not an option in `WP_Query`? I doubt if you can solve this reasonably in just a flat query.

Comment: Is row 5 considred unique compared with row 1: `title2 content2`? And,  as @GolezTrol mentioned, why is row 1 considered the "authoritative" unique row instead of some other row?

Comment: Would a result set containing rows 2 and 4 be incorrect?  Or one containing rows 2, 6, and 7?  Neither title nor content would be duplicated in either.

Comment: It seems to be like what OP wants is to have a `SELECT DISTINCT title FROM posts` as well as `SELECT DISTINCT content FROM posts`, the issue is that we have no clues how to join them together.

Comment: why The fifth row ( 5 title2 content2 ) is not unique ?

Comment: @user2915422, voted to close for reasons of Unclear what you are asking. It is important to stick around and clear up uncertainties.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM posts GROUP BY title ORDER BY id) as subQ GROUP BY subQ.content ORDER BY subQ.id`

Comment: @GolezTrol row 1 is not more unique. But it should display the first result and then after that it should only display unique results.

Row 2 an 3 should not be displayed because the title is the same and already in the results (row 1)
Row 4 should not be displayed because that content is already in row 1.

Row 5 should be displayed as mentioned by pjd 

Row 6 and 7 should not be displaye because of the title or content are not unique.

Comment: @pjd Row 5 is indeed unique, good spot. Also Row 1 is more authoritative simply because it's the first result. The order however does not matter much,

Comment: I am pretty sure this cannot be done with a query alone. This is an iterative process where you loop through the rows and compare each with the already accepted rows. You need a programming language to do that. I don't know, however, if MySQL's stored procedures would be able to do that (by filling a temporary table step by step probably).

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT * from posts GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT * from posts GROUP BY content HAVING count(*) = 1;
```